# How to assert in async function within Promise?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, asynchronous, promise, mocha.js

When using Mocha for unit testing, I have a situation like this that I need to test:

```
it('should assert true blah blah blah', function () {

  return doSomething() // <-- returns a Promise
    .then(function(value) {

      return setTimeout(function() {

        assert.equal(something, true);

      },1000);

    });

});
```

So I have a Promise that is returned from a function, and then I need to do an assert within an async `setTimeout` after the Promise has been resolved. The above code appears to always pass the test no matter what. In fact, it seems like the `setTimeout` never ever runs. If I put a `console.log` in the `setTimeout` it never prints out. Mocha finishes the unit test and moves on.

What is the proper way to test something like this? I see there is some sort of `done()` method with Mocha but I'm not sure if that is something I should use with this or not. I don't fully understand it.

Comment: You are `return`ing `setTimeout(function)` from `.then()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you return a promise to Mocha, it will assume the test is complete when the promise resolves.

If you have some non-promise-based asynchronous function to test after the promise resolves, you can use a `done` callback *instead* of returning a promise:

```
it('should assert true blah blah blah', function (done) {

  doSomething()
    .then(function(value) {

      setTimeout(function() {

        assert.equal(something, true);
        done();

      },1000);

    })
    .catch(done);
});
```

Note that you should also include a `catch` so that any promise rejection is passed to the `done` callback, as Mocha understands Node-style errors and will fail the test if it receives one.

Alternatively, you could use a completely promise-based approach and could create a `Promise` to enclose your asynchronous function:

```
it('should assert true blah blah blah', function () {

  return doSomething()
    .then(function(value) {

      return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

        setTimeout(function() {

          try {
            assert.equal(something, true);
            resolve();
          } catch (error) {
            reject(error);
          }

        },1000);

      });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use `setTimeout()` to "wait" the Promise to be resolved. In stead, when it the Promise is resolved, the `.then()` will be call. You simply just use the `value` or do some `assert` there, that's it.

Comment: The `setTimeout` is not there to wait on the Promise to be resolved. It's there for a specific reason that is not explained in the simplified example. Something to do with expiration of a cached object, which is what I am testing. The example in the question is greatly simplified.

Answer (score 0):

Because Mocha will work [intelligently with functions that return Promises](https://mochajs.org/#working-with-promises), you could also use the new `async`/`await` syntax, which implicitly returns Promises!

```
import 'babel-polyfill';

it('should assert true blah blah blah', async function () {
  // `doSomething` is a function that returns a Promise
  // `something` will be the resolved value
  let something = await doSomething();
  assert.equal(something, true);
});
```

A little bit of setup is required, but I think it's worth it considering how nice and flat your testing code looks in the end. And it's super easy to write.

You'll probably want the following packages – `es2015` and `es2016` are optional here, but if you're transpiling your testing code, you might as well include these. You'll end up wanting them anyway. `babel-register` is used for the require hook and `babel-polyfill` is used for the regenerator runtime.

```
$ npm install --save-dev babel-cli           \
                         babel-register      \
                         babel-polyfill      \
                         babel-preset-es2015 \
                         babel-preset-es2016 \
                         babel-preset-es2017
```

Your **.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "es2016", "es2017"]
}
```

Your **package.json**

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha --compilers js:babel-register"
  }
}
```